# Time.now returns wrong result in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm running an RSpec test suite with capybara in my Rails app.
When I put `binding.pry` inside of a test, and try `Time.current`, I get `=> Tue, 15 Dec 2015 00:06:30 UTC +00:00`, which is three months ago. As far as my basic knowledge of geography goes, there isn't a time zone that has a 3 months difference with EST. So what am I missing here? :-)

Running same query in development environment (i.e. through `rails console`) returns correct result.

Comment: Did you stub any time related method?

Comment: can you please show us the source code? It would be better. Because without seeing the source code just guessing is not probably a good idea.

Comment: Does the time in tests change or it's always the same?

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing where someone has used the [Timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to call `Timecop.freeze` in a spec to freeze time at some specific date/time, but has forgotten to add statement like `after { Timecop.return }` to prevent the time freeze from leaking into other specs in the suite.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti I've seen that too and I've actually added an after filter which does `Timecop.return` after every spec, stops any confusion later on

Comment: Thanks guys, it was Timecop!! :)

Comment: @PetrGazarov great, will post as an answer, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have specs in your suite that use [the Timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop). So, have a look for every instance of `Timecop.freeze` and ensure there is a corresponding `Timecop.return` statement in order to do proper teardown of the time freeze and prevent the unexpected side effect of it leaking into other specs in your suite.  Here is an example from [the gem's README](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/blob/master/README.markdown):

```
describe "some set of tests to mock" do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(1990))
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  it "should do blah blah blah" do
  end
end
```